# Android listview with checkedtextview

Tags: android, listview, checkedtextview

I have a listview with CheckedTextView. I want when select the item add its value to a list and when deselect remove the value from list. I don't know why i couldn't get accurate value. Thanks in advance........

Here is my code

```
      listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                    View view, int position, long id) {



                                CheckedTextView ctv=(CheckedTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.addonsItem);

                            if (ctv.isChecked()) {

                                Temp.addonsIdList.add(addonsiDList.get(position));
                                Temp.addonsNameList.add(addonsList.get(position));
                                Temp.addonsPriceList.add(addonsPriceList.get(position));
                                ctv.setChecked(false);



                            }else{

                                Temp.addonsIdList.remove(addonsiDList.get(position));
                                Temp.addonsNameList.remove(addonsList.get(position));
                                Temp.addonsPriceList.remove(addonsPriceList.get(position));
                                ctv.setChecked(true);



                            }
```

adapter getView code

```
   @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.addons_text, parent, false);
        CheckedTextView checkTV=(CheckedTextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.addonsItem);

        checkTV.setText(Temp.addonsName.get(position));                 
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Did your selection changing while scrolling?

Comment: yes. sometimes app crashed.

Comment: Where is the adapter getView code?

Comment: @ Amsheer   i have attached my code.

Comment: Check my answer this will solve your crash

Comment: For your next issue while scrolling your selection changing. For this you need some more changes. And i need some details. Do you have any ID ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

You need to implement else part first like the following

```
ViewHolder holder;

     if (convertView == null) {
    holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.addons_text, parent, false);
            holder.checkTV=(CheckedTextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.addonsItem);


    convertView.setTag(holder);               
        }else{
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
     holder.checkTV.setText(Temp.addonsName.get(position));
```

And then create class

```
class ViewHolder {
            CheckedTextView checkTV;
}
```

**Edit 1:**

For your scrolling issue you need to follow the steps.

`Step 1.` Add your selected row value in a ArrayList

`Step 2.` in your getView add one condition

```
if(yourArrayList.contains(selected_value)){
holder.checkTV.setChecked(true);
}else{
holder.checkTV.setChecked(false);
}
```

Comment: I have also tried this. But the problem is i select one item but shows selected another item.

Comment: I know that. So only add comment in your question. Do you have any ID field?

Comment: I don't want to confuse. Tell me addonsIdList is it integer ArrayList?

Comment: No its a string ArrayList

Comment: Check my Edit. Try to follow that.

Comment: Finally i solved it, How chilly !! i just comment out CheckTextView.setChecked(true).  now its working fine what i wanted.